# Tensor product of algebraic number field with p-adic field

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the field of $p$-adic numbers and let $K$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite degree. The Wikipedia page "Tensor product of fields" states that $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a product of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, in $1-1$ correspondence with the completions of $K$ for extensions of the $p$-adic metric on $\mathbb{Q}$. Why is this true?

Comment: I believe this is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401266/11619). Because I gave an answer there, and I am not an expert in this area I refrain from casting the first vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: This is Proposition 8.3 in Neukirch, you may use it as a reference.