# Galois is conserved under completions

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

let $K / \mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois number field with ring of integers $O_K $. take a prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ of $O_K$ lying over $p\mathbb{Z}$. then we obtain the induced field extension $K_{\mathfrak P} /\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $K_{\mathfrak P}$ completion of $K$ with respect $\mathfrak P$. why is this extension also Galois?

since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has characteristic zero the induced extension is separable. what about normal? since $K / \mathbb{Q}$ normal because Galois we can find a family $\{f_i \}_{i \in I}$ of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $K$ is nothing but their splitting field. by construction all $\{f_i \}_{i \in I}$ split also in $K_{\mathfrak P}$ since $K \subset K_{\mathfrak P}$. unfortunately I don't see how to continue from here...

Comment: Write $K = \mathbf{Q}[x]/p(x)$, so $p(x)$ is separable. Over $\mathbf{Q}_p$, the polynomial $p(x)$ factors as $\prod p_i(x)$, and the fields $K_{\mathbf{P}_i}$ are none other than the fields $\mathbf{Q}_p[x]/p_i(x)$. (Equivalently, $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$). To show that $K_i = K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ is normal, it suffices to show that $K_i$ contains all the roots of $p_i(x)$ and is thus its splitting field. But this field contains $K$, and thus (since $K$ is a splitting field) it also contains all the roots of $p(x)$, which includes the roots of $p_i(x)$ for every $i$.

Comment: @The Piper: why the completion $K_{P_i}$ equals $\mathbb{Q}_p[x]/p_i(x)$?

Comment: If $p = \prod \mathfrak{p}^{e_i}_i$ in a number field $K$, then $\mathcal{O}_K/p^n \simeq \prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^{n e_i}_i$. Can you see from this that $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ and thus $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$?

Comment: @ThePiper: the last two aren't clear. $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$ is just the localization wrt the multiplicative system $O_K \backslash p$. how do you obtain the direct product on the right side? the conclusion $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}
$ is also unclear

Comment: If they are unclear, then I suggest spending time thinking about them some more, because they should be transparent.

Comment: @ThePiper: ok, regarding $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$: obviously we have an inclusion between the multiplicative systems $S_i:= O_K \backslash \mathfrak{p_i} \subset O_K \backslash p:= S$ this induces $O_{K,\mathfrak{p_i}} \subset O_{K,p}= \mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$. Do you mean that $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ as $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules or rings?

Comment: since in the category of modules finite products and sums coinside so $\prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}=\oplus \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ as modules and by universal property of direct sum/coproduct we obtain $\oplus \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i} \to O_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$. since all $\mathfrak{p_i}$ are maximal it should be (I have to think a bit more why) an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules.

Comment: question: do you mean the identification $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ as modules or as rings? regarding "ring" case I have now idea what to do.

Comment: As rings --- start with $\mathcal{O}_K/p^n = \prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^{n e_i}_i$ as mentioned then take inverse limits in $n$.

Comment: I see... then on the left we observe that since inverse limits behave well under tensor extensions (in the sense $\varprojlim B/p^n \cong B \otimes \varprojlim A/pA$)and on the right hand side the $\{ \prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^{n e_i}_i \}_n$ form a cofinal system of $\prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ so limits coinside.

Comment: could you give a hint for $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$?

Comment: $(p) = (\prod_j P_j)^e$ then $ \varprojlim O_K/(p)^n = \varprojlim O_K/(\prod_j P_j)^{en} = \varprojlim \prod_j O_K/P_j^{en}=\prod_j \varprojlim O_K/P_j^n = \prod_j O_{\displaystyle K_{P_j}}$

Comment: this gives the equation $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}
$ for the rings of intergers. how does it help to obtain $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}
$?

Comment: Tim, from $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ you immediately get $K\otimes\Bbb{Q}_p=\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ (vector spaces are flat so tensoring with $\Bbb{Q}_p$ preserves quotients). Then the Chinese remainder theorem isolates the component fields $\prod K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401266/11619)

Comment: I understand that by Chinese remainder thm we obtain the splitting $K \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p \cong \prod\limits_{i=1}^g K_{p_i}$. CRT gives $K_{p_i}=\mathbf{Q}_p[x]/p_i(x)$ and the discussion above donates us $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i}$ with $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}= Frac(\mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}_i})$ by proceeding to limit & using cofinal argument.  the problem is still to derive from this that then the $K_{p_i}$ already coincide with completion $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ of $K$ wrt $p_i$.

Comment: unfortunately I still uncertain how we conclude $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$. again to clarify the notations the polynomial $p(x)$ splits to $\prod p_i(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$. we denote by $K_{p_i}=\mathbf{Q}_p[x]/p_i(x)$ and by $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ the completion of $K$ with respect the prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}_i:=(p_i)$. we know by CRT that $K \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p \cong \prod\limits_{i=1}^g K_{p_i}$ and by taking inverse limits we also saw

Comment: that $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p = \prod \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{P}_i}$ where $\mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{P}_i}$ are the rings of integers of $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$. why is that sufficient to obtain $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}= K_{p_i}$ or equivalently $K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p = \prod K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}
$? sorry for frequently annoying but I just don't see final step